# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '55,201' to data type int

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, left-join

I am trying to build query to get districts that are saved as string using SQL Server. Here is the table "FranchiseInfoes"

```
FranchiseInfoPK  | ClientName   | Email       |   DistrictsFK

      2            |    asasd   | sd@sd.com   |  20,30,10
```

How I can select all FranchiseInfoes with districts?

Here is my code

```
SELECT
    dbo.FranchiseInfoes.FranchiseInfoPK,
    dbo.FranchiseInfoes.ClientName,
    dbo.FranchiseInfoes.Email,
    dbo.District.DistrictName,
FROM dbo.FranchiseInfoes
LEFT JOIN dbo.District ON dbo.District.DistrictPK = dbo.FranchiseInfoes.DistrictsFK
```

Comment: It seems your schema is denormalized: you appear to have a many:many relationship between `FranchiseInfoes` and `District`, so you would need a third table `FranchiseInfoe_District` with both foreign keys. Side point: three-part naming of columns `schema.table.column` is deprecated, you should use the table alias instead

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. "How i can select all FranchiseInfoes with districts" sounds like you want `select FranchiseInfoPK from FranchiseInfos where DistrictsFK is not NULL;`. Perhaps you could clarify the question, e.g. what results do you expect from your extensive sample data?

Comment: Your query has a syntax error - please ensure you post working examples.

Comment: **NEVER** put delimited data in a column like that! This cries out for an additional table. Do that, and suddenly this query is easy, and will run many times faster (because indexing will work properly).

Answer (score 0):

A 3rd table to normalize the data is probably your best bet, but if you can't do that:

If you're using SQL Server 2016 or later, you have access to the `string_split` function which can break out that '20,30,10' into a table. Use that in a `cross apply` to make 1 row for each value. Wrap that in a common table expression and join to the District table:

```
    with SplitFranchiseInfoes as (
       select FranchiseInfoes.FranchiseInfoPK
            , FranchiseInfoes.ClientName
            , FranchiseInfoes.Email
            , itvf.DistrictsFK
         from dbo.FranchiseInfoes
       cross apply (
          select value as DistrictsFK
            from string_split(FranchiseInfoes.DistrictsFK,',')
       ) itvf
    )
       select SplitFranchiseInfoes.FranchiseInfoPK
            , SplitFranchiseInfoes.ClientName
            , SplitFranchiseInfoes.Email
            , District.DistrictName
         from SplitFranchiseInfoes
   left join dbo.District
          on District.DistrictPK = SplitFranchiseInfoes.DistrictsFK;
```

If you don't have access to `string_split`, you could craft your own function to do it (I recommend looking up string splitting with a Tally or numbers table). But if you can't add a 3rd table for normalization, you probably can't add a Tally table and User-defined function to split strings either.